# Preventing Website Icon from Appearing in Search Results with React SEO Setup

Tags: reactjs, seo, react-helmet

I have developed a website using React and implemented SEO features using the react-helmet-async package. However, when I search for my website on search engines, the default React icon (favicon) appears alongside the website title and description in the search results. I want to display the actual website icon instead of the default React icon in search engine results. How can I achieve this while keeping the website title and description intact?

In my app.js file, I have used the react-helmet component to set various meta tags, including the website icon. Here is an example of the code:
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

```
<Helmet>
  <title>Home - [Website Name]</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Home - [Website Name]" />
  <meta property="og:image" content={logo} />
  <link rel="icon" href={logo} />
  <!-- Other meta tags -->
</Helmet>
```

Additionally, in my index.js file, the HelmetProvider wraps the application. Here is an example of the code:

```
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelmetProvider>
    <App />
  </HelmetProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Furthermore, in my index.html file, I have included the website icon and other necessary meta tags. Here is an example of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Other meta tags -->
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Other link tags -->
    <title>[website name]</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Other HTML content -->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- Other scripts -->
  </body>
</html>
```